# Issue creating tag-cloud in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-cloud

My project contains tagcloud and I am following the sample on:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/107/Creating-a-Tag-Cloud-using-ASP.NET-MVC-and-the-Entity-Framework

My problem is, that I can't call the action from the controller to assign different fonts based on the frequency of my tags. If anyone has done this before through other examples or this example I would appreciate if you can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that I needed to add the controller to my view as a namespace to be able to call the method that calculates the frequency thanks